# Angular 6 7 8 - Drag and drop + virtual scroll + Observable

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, observable, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

I need to have Drag&drop working with Virtual scroll. Data source of my VS is observable. I tried this code but it's not working, no changes at the VS list, just animation:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="observableData | async as items">
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport
    cdkDropList 
    #virtualScroller
    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <mat-list>
        <mat-list-item 
            cdkDrag     
            *cdkVirtualFor="let item of items; let i = index; trackBy: trackByIdx">
            <h4 matLine cdkDragHandle>
                List item Title
            </h4>
            <p matLine cdkDragHandle>
                List item text
            </p>                
        </mat-list-item>
    </mat-list>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

and here is my ts handler:

```
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<any[]>) {
     const vsStartIndex = this.virtualScroller.getRenderedRange().start;
     moveItemInArray( this.observableData.value, event.previousIndex + 
     vsStartIndex, event.currentIndex + vsStartIndex);
}
```

How do I implement d&d with Observable lists?

Answer (score 2):

You must pass data to list `[cdkDropListData]="items"`

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport
cdkDropList
[cdkDropListData]="items"
#virtualScroller
(cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
```